# Using external js to sort tables in Angular2

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, semantic-ui

I have a problem. Im creating an app in Angular2 using Semantic UI. In the documentation said that you can create a sortable table. it say that you have to import a tablesort.js and call $('table').tablesort() when the DOM is ready.

My problem start when it doesnt recognize that .tablesort is a method. It say that its not a method from Jquery so i dont know how to do work correctly

Here is my code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from "services/user.service";
import { Bet } from "models/bet";
import * as $ from 'jquery';
@Component({
    selector: 'history',
    templateUrl: 'history.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./history.component.css'],
})

export class HistoryComponent implements OnInit {

    url: string;
    bets = [];
    constructor(private userService: UserService) {
        this.url = 'http://localhost:3000/bets/history';
    }
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.userService.getHistory(this.url).subscribe(this.sucess.bind(this), this.error);
        $('table').tablesort();

    }
}
```

And in my index im importing:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="semantic/components/tablesort.js"></script>
```

How can  i do that Jquery recognize a external JS and can use the function from that JS.

Comment: Try to import jquery with <script> tag before tablestort.js and then in component add this: declare var jQuery:any; and remove import * as $ from 'jquery';

Comment: It say the same, tablesort doesnt exist on type 'JQuery'.

Well i think that my problem is with tablesort.js because doesnt load correctly. When i launch the app in my browser i get this errors: GET http://localhost:4200/semantic/components/tablesort.js " so it cant be load correctly.